# Suma de dos campos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando sumar dos campos pero no consigo hacerlo mi estructura es esta.

```
INSERT INTO `servicio` (`id`, `Nombre`, `Caida1`, `Caida2`, `Caida3`, `Caida4`, `Confirmado`) 
VALUES
(1, 'TEST', 54, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(2, 'TEST2', 19, 8, 1, 1, 0);
```

He intentado hacer uso de Sum y me da error no sé que estoy haciendo mal y con Count solo me cuenta las lineas SELECT COUNT(*) Caida1,Caida2 FROM servicio

Intento sumar Caida1 de la linea 1 y 2 sacar el total para un echo.

Comment: y que es lo que tratas de sumar?

Comment: La sintaxis del sum es:

    SELECT SUM(column_name)
    FROM table_name
    WHERE condition; ¿Podrias dar más detalles de lo que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Intento sumar Caida1 de la id 1 y 2 es decir los valores 54+19

Comment: select sum (Caida1) as valor_total  from servicio . Ya lo tendrías no hace falta ningun group by ni order by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no indicas cual es el error, pero podrías hacer esto:

```
SELECT SUM(Caida1) as total FROM servicio
```

Eso debería de sumarte todo el contenido de esa columna y almacenarlo en a variable total

Por otro lado también puedes sumar dos columnas de manera lineal y retornar su suma total, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(Caida1+Caida2) as total FROM servicio
```

Comment: Eso era amigo estaba cometiendo yo el error, muchas gracias.